# Java: System.out.print Error in main() | out needs to be an object in abstract class (not)

Tags: java, system

https://github.com/AquaSolid/Interactions

[image]

cannot find symbol 
symbol: variable out
location: class System   // <-- System is my Abstract class

```
 public class Interactions {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println("Welcome to Interactions."); }}
```

Comment: could you please *clarify* a bit

Comment: I recommend looking at the picture. I honestly have no idea what is going on, probably an inheritance problem, perhaps? The "out" in System.out.println shows an error.

Comment: Don't create a class called 'System'..

Comment: Ahaah, thank you, sorry to bother you all, it's probably that.Not probably, definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hidden java.lang.System by adding a System class in your package. This can be fixed by referring to java.lang.System by its full path:

```
 public class Interactions {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    java.lang.System.out.println("Welcome to Interactions."); }}
```

Comment: While using the fully qualified name would solve the issue, it might be worth noting that it could be quite confusing. Renaming the "System" class might be a better idea, but this would definitely still solve the problem! +1

Comment: Completely fixed, dumb rookie mistake, thank you and everyone else. Renamed it to Organization.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a class called 'System', I see that you have a "System.java".

Give it some other name.

[System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) is a built-in Java class!

Comment: It really isn't a problem to create a class 'System'. There is a simple workaround. See my answer.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Yes, I do know that it's not a problem to do that. I have commented on your answer, no doubt it's good, but I don't think it should be encouraged. :)